# AWS RDS notification when record is added to a table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

Is this possible?

I did my research but this is the only possible events for RDS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html

Mostly for maintenance type events but what I want is - let's I have a RDS Oracle table called Users. Whenever a record is inserted in the table, an event or stream can be picked up by a Lambda and do the necessary action.

Comment: Yes RDS event notification are not for table/schema level.SInce i havent tried it yet, i cannot answer specific answer, but i did find options which may help you 1) Monitor RDS logs and set up cloudwatch alarms to get notification (docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/…) 2) Monitoring RDS API calls for insert/update using cloudtrail and setup sns (docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/…) 3) Monitoring Oracle Database Activity Streams (docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/…)

Comment: Thanks @JatinMehrotra. Is there anyway I can chat with you? I have some follow up questions

Comment: you can connect with me on linkedin or if there any follow up questions, feel free to ask ons tack, someone or the other will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, not with the existing events you refer to - these are for monitoring the RDS service, not what you actually use it for, i.e. contents auditing (manipulation/tracking)

You can of course create notifications when an insert occurs, but you'll probably need to build/setup a few things.

A couple of ideas:

1. Building something closer to the database logic, i.e. in your code base add something that fires a SQS / SNS event.
2. If you can't (or don't want to) modify the logic that handle the database, maybe you could add a trigger that gets fired on INSERTs to the user table. Unfortunately I don't think there's support to execute a Lamdba from a trigger (as it is possible to do with PostgreSQL at the moment).
3. Set up a database activity stream from RDS to Kinesis to monitor the INSERTS. This is a bit of a additional infrastructure to set up, so it might be a bit too much depending on your use case:
   *"Database Activity Streams is an Amazon RDS feature that provides a near real-time stream of the activity in your Oracle DB instance. Amazon RDS pushes activities to an Amazon Kinesis data stream."*
   From Kinesis, you can configure AWS Lambda to consume the stream and take action on INSERT events.

Some references:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-example.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/DBActivityStreams.Enabling.html

Comment: Thanks @Niclas. By the way, activity streams for RDS can only be done on Oracle? will other DBs work too? like SQL server, postgres or mysql?

Comment: It should be fine with both Aurora Postgres & Mysql. There are some limitations on which instance class and region are supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.Overview.html 
Can't find anything on Microsoft SQL so I'm not sure about the support there (havn't used it)

Comment: Hi @Niclas . In my scenario, the Database belongs to a third party account. They rejected the idea of setting up a trigger in the DB as they think it may cause an overhead for our benefit. If I am going with the Kinesis stream option, can I setup their DB activity to be captured from my AWS account without disturbing their environment? Please note that there is cross-account data transfer that might be required here.